# curl: (7) Failed connect to 127.0.0.1:5984; Connection refused [Sometimes]

Tags: linux, azure, centos, couchdb

I have a couchdb database installed in a centos machine in azure. what's strange is that when i try to run 'curl http://127.0.0.1:5984' in terminal it give me expected result sometimes.

{"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"2.3.0","git_sha":"07ea0c7","uuid":"d36b551cb35122db8d088982c4216c9b","features":["pluggable-storage-engines","scheduler"],"vendor":{"name":"The Apache Software Foundation"}}

but sometimes i am getting this:
curl: (7) Failed connect to 127.0.0.1:5984; Connection refused

this is having frequently i means sometimes i get result and sometimes i don't.

what am i doing wrong??

Comment: It sounds like your server is unstable. Check your CouchDB logs.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps your virtual machine has `iptables` rule that deny the traffic go in to port `5984`. Try to open with following command:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5984 -j ACCEPT
```

If it still not working, try to turn off `firewalld` service:

```
service firewalld stop
```

Comment: This would cause it to always fail, not only sometimes.